# How do I use connect to DB2 with DBI and mod_perl?

Tags: perl, db2, dbi, mod-perl

I'm having issues with getting DBI's IBM DB2 driver to work with mod_perl. My test script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

{
    my $q;
    my $dsn;
    my $username;
    my $password;
    my $sth;
    my $dbc;
    my $row;

    $q = CGI->new;
    print $q->header;
    print $q->start_html();

    $dsn = "DBI:DB2:SAMPLE";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";

    print "<pre>".$q->escapeHTML(Dumper(\%ENV))."</pre>";

    $dbc = DBI->connect($dsn, $username, $password);

    $sth = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE FIELD='SOMETHING'");
    $sth->execute();
    $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref();
    print "<pre>".$q->escapeHTML(Dumper($row))."</pre>";

    print $q->end_html;
}
```

This script works as CGI but not under mod_perl. I get this error in apache's error log:

```
DBD::DB2::dr connect warning: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Apache/DBI.pm line 190.
DBI connect('SAMPLE','username',...) failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified at /data/www/perl/test.pl line 15
```

First of all, why is it using ODBC? The native DB2 driver is installed (hence it works as CGI).

Running Apache 2.2.3, mod_perl 2.0.4 under RHEL5.

This guy had the same problem as me:
http://www.mail-archive.com/dbi-users@perl.org/msg22909.html
But I have no idea how he fixed it. What does mod_php4 have to do with mod_perl?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm having no luck with google.

**Update**:

As james2vegas pointed out, the problem has something to do with PHP: I disable PHP all together I get the a different error:

```
 Total Environment allocation failure! Did you set up your DB2 client environment?
```

I believe this error is to do with environment variables not being set up correctly, namely `DB2INSTANCE`. However, I'm not able to turn off PHP to resolve this problem (I need it for some legacy applications). So I now have 2 questions:

1. How can I fix the original issue without disabling PHP all together?
2. How can I fix the environment issue?

I've set DB2INSTANCE, DB2_PATH and SQLLIB variables correctly using `SetEnv` and `PerlSetEnv` in `httpd.conf`, but with no luck.

Note: I've edited the code to determine if the problem was to do with Global Variable Persistence.

Comment: What that refers to is that the wrong library is being loaded by php into apache's process, and that is affecting the script when its running under mod_perl (also in the same apache process) as opposed to CGI (which is its own separate process), might be worth testing this without PHP.

Comment: You could try getting DBD::DB2::dr::data_sources(); it should return an array of data sources, make sure it includes SAMPLE.

Comment: You are correct, if I disable PHP I get the a different error:

    Total Environment allocation failure!  Did you set up your DB2 client environment?

Which is a problem itself, but I've seen this before. In the past it meant that the environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not set. Now I DO actually have it set using 'SetEnv' and 'PerlSetEnv' but they seem to have no effect.

But additionally, the server runs PHP and perl, so I can't just turn off PHP to fix the problem. How can I fix the initial issue without disabling PHP al together?

Comment: If PHP is not using ODBC, you could try rebuilding it without ODBC support.

You might try pre-loading DBD::DB2 and setting the DB2 environment variables in your mod_perl startup script.

Comment: Thanks james2vegas. Is the only way to disable ODBC by rebuild it? Or can I just disable it in php.ini? I'm just asking because PHP was installed as a package, not compiled from source.

Comment: Got it! The problem was with pdo_odbc, so by disabling it in /etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini fixed the issue. Also, you were correct about setting the environment variables in the startup script.

I'm new to stack overflow (so I'm not familiar with the practices), but did you want to post the answer so I can give you the points?

Comment: According to http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Perl/perl.dbi.users/2010-01/msg00051.html you could try setting the environment variable PERL_DL_NONLAZY to 1 (you could try doing this prior to pre-loading DBD::DB2 in your startup script. (ignore this, since you got it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears solved, for reference: disable PHP's ODBC support in /etc/php.d/pdo_odbc.ini, set the environment variables and preload [DBD::DB2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-DB2) in mod_perl's startup script, though it might be possible to use [PERL_DL_NONLAZY](http://www.perl.com/lpt/a/520#PERL_DL_NONLAZY) set to 1 to force loading of the correct library.

Comment: Ah, so the DBD was being loaded funny?  I wish this stuff would get documented more... it seems like it's easy to run into the hard way. :(

Comment: The problem is that both DB2's and ODBC's shared libraries export identically named SQL_XXXX functions, and the latter was overriding the former.

Answer (score 1):

Plain old DBI won't work in mod_perl; it goes all wibbly when your process forks and you try to use your db handle again.  You need to use [Apache::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Apache::DBI) (it's a drop-in replacement for DBI), or even better, use a post-modern DBI wrapper like [DBIx::Connector](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx::Connector).

You can read more details here, at [Apache's guide to using mod_perl with relational databases](http://perl.apache.org/docs/1.0/guide/databases.html#Apache__DBI___Initiate_a_persistent_database_connection).

Comment: Actually on second look it does appear that you've got Apache::DBI installed... I'm about to get on the train, but I'll dig deeper when I get back to a terminal.

Comment: Thanks man, yeah I do have Apache::DBI installed and loaded in httpd.conf.